# I am getting less data using entity in MVVM

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added view into model. After that i created Domain service.

I tried to add the view data to grid.

```
VReportViewer.GrdReport.ItemsSource = dcBusinessAccountingContext.SalesDetailViews;
```

If i run with same view in sql server. I am getting 170 rows data. But using entity i am getting only 94 rows data.Can any body give me the idea any where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the application on the same database as you are in SSMS?

Comment: Is entity framework having problems mapping the other columns into properties that it can display?  Are any of those missing columns binary content?

Comment: columns are mapped correctly and binary content also correct.

Comment: You tagged it as mvc, but you talk about MVVM. Do you really mean mvc or do you mean wpf? Because MVC is a pattern as is MVVM. Or are you trying to use MVVM in a ASP.NET MVC Project?

Comment: I am trying MVVM in ASP.Net mvc project.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is meant for MVC, not MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

check entity key in view into edmx.

Into the ADO.Net entity data model (edmx file) you can find table and view, when
a new view is imported some fileds are automatically set as "entiy key" (click on filed then check property).
Sometimes the auto generated entity key are worong, in this case when you run the linq query results are different from sql.
To solve the problem find a correct "entity key" or remove all "entity key" (readonly view) , check also nullble/non nullable property foreach filed and set in the right way.

This works for me in similar case.
(sorry for late)
Hope this help.